# Sign Error: solved differential equation $y'' = -b\,y'-g$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got solved a differential equation here, but it still seems to differ from the textbook solution by a wrong sign: again it's about $y'' = -b\, y'-g$. The solution process goes like:

\begin{align*}
&y'' = -b\, y'-g \quad{\vert\:\text{let}\, y' = u} \\[6pt]
& u' = -b\,u-g\\[6pt]
&\frac{\mathrm{du}}{-b\,u-g}=\mathrm{dt}\\[6pt]
&\ln(-b\,u-g) = -b\,t +C\\[6pt]
&b\,u = -C\,e^{-b\,t}-g\\[6pt]
&b\,y' = -Ce^{-b\,t}-g\\[6pt]
&b\,y = \frac{C}{b}e^{-b\,t}-g\,t+C
\end{align*}

The textbook claims now $y = k\,(e^{-b\,t}-1)-\frac{g}{b}$ would be the solution. I can't figure out how? To me it looks like $+1$. Even if their solution seems physically right.

Comment: Sign error. Write $\frac{\mathrm{du}}{b\,u+g}=-\mathrm{dt}$

Comment: Still leads to the same solution. I guess the problem is, the added constant has to be negative so $-C$ instead of $+C$. One can probably just know this with physics acknowledgment

Comment: The exact solution of this DE is $$y=c_1 e^{-b t}-\frac{g t}{b}+c_2$$ (remember that $-c_1$ is a constant; so, rename it  $c_{\text{whatever_you_want}}$

Comment: Oh, that's pretty new to me to chose negative constants. Especially as this appears to be the only valid physical solution.